# What is meant by "representative of a University" in French universities?

Tags: supervision, united-kingdom, internship, visiting

I am planning to visit a British laboratory. They asked me to sign a form by *the representative of my home university*. I do not understand who this representative is supposed to be: our director or which other person?

Comment: Guessing a bit, but it is probably anyone authorized to "speak" for the university. A department head might be enough. I'll tag this UK to wake up our British members

Comment: Might help to have some context about what the form is to have a better idea of what exactly they need.

Comment: How would anyone here know what an unspecified British laboratory means by this in the context of some unspecified form? Just ask them if it's not clear to you.